# How to get the City and Country of an OSM node or way?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am parsing country extracts of OSM data. What I want to is the get the name of the City and Country that that point or way belongs to. Is this possible? How can I go about getting this information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To retrieve this information you need a geocoder, unless the node has the relevant [address tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:addr). [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is a good geocoder for OSM and there are [some more](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines).

If you have the ID of the node or way, then just use Nominatim's reverse geocoding capabilities. This is the result for [way 206488036](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/206488036): http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&osm_type=W&osm_id=206488036

Change the *osm_type* parameter if you want to query for nodes (*N*) or relations (*R*) instead of ways.